# Woocommerce Variation Product not refreshing on save

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce store with simple as well as variation products.

I've noticed that only on saving variation products, I get an output like this, on a blank screen:

```
string(7) "instock" string(0) "" string(7) "instock" string(0) "" string(7) "instock" string(0) ""
```

I then either refresh the page, in which case it takes me to the index page of the Posts post type, or I have to press back in the browser.

I've also noticed that this error doesn't occur on my local machine but only on the live server.

The data is saved but the page doesn't refresh.

Could anybody point me in the right direction as to what may cause this?

Comment: Commence standard debug procedures. Try a default theme. Disable other plugins and re-enable one at a time.